# SSL certificate error

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, litespeed

New to SSL. I had a certificate signed and I am trying to get the cert I generated loaded into LiteSpeed. However I have one issue.

```
2012-11-01 20:30:33.121 NOTICE  [PID: 28139]: start cgid: 28140, /usr/local/lsws/bin/httpd
2012-11-01 20:30:33.122 ERROR   [SSL] Config SSL Context with Certificate File: /usr/local/lsws/domain.org.csr and Key File:/usr/local/lsws/domain.org.csr get SSL error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
2012-11-01 20:30:33.122 INFO    Stop listener *:443.
2012-11-01 20:30:33.122 ERROR   [config:server:listener:SSL] failed to start SSL listener on address *:443!
```

The location of the .crt and .key I generated are under /usr/local/lsws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.csr` file is only used once, to send to the CA to get the certificate.  Your web server config only needs the `.key` and the `.crt` file.  (And potentially a chain file if your CA requires that.  They should have mentioned it and supplied one if they do.)

I'm not familiar with LiteSpeed but I would guess that the **Certificate File** mentioned in the error message should be the `.crt` and the **Key File** mentioned in the error message should be the `.key`.

The [docs look to support my guess](http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php?id=litespeed_wiki:ssl_cert_install).  Once you have got it up and running, check with with the [SSL checker](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to make sure it's all correct.